# while creating tree node with popup modal getting error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

here my goal is to create a tree on button click one popup modal has to opent where i have to input the values and and has to store in database and as well show in the tree,and also in the context menu which node we select there also an popup modal to open and get node ,delete node and renaming has to happen

here its my controller view

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            return View();
        }
        //[HttpPost]
        //public IActionResult Index(string selectedItems)
        //{
        //    List<TreeViewModel> items=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TreeViewModel>>(selectedItems);
        //    return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //}

        public IActionResult GetTree()
        {
            List<TreeViewModel> nodes = new List<TreeViewModel>();
            foreach (ParentClass type in _db.parent)
            {
                nodes.Add(new TreeViewModel
                {
                    id = type.Id.ToString(),
                    parent = "#",
                    text = type.ParentName
                });
            }
            foreach (ChildClass list in _db.child)
            {
                nodes.Add(new TreeViewModel
                {
                    id = list.Id.ToString(),
                    parent = list.parentId.ToString(),
                    text = list.ChildName
                });
            }
            return Json(nodes);
        }
      [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ParentClass parent = new ParentClass();
            return PartialView("_HomePartial",parent);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(ParentClass parent)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.parent.Add(parent);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return PartialView("_HomePartial", parent);
            }
           
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

and my index view where i am giving button for popup modal to insert tree node in my code it taking only parent

```
<div class="container" id="placeHolder">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="row pt-3">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p class="text-primary text-light">File Structure
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-end">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
              data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-bs-target="#Addnode"
                    data-url="@Url.Action("Create")"><i class="bi 
              bi-plus-square-fill"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="simpleJsTree">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col=9">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javacript for tree view

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://localhost:44376/Home/GetTree",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            createJSTree(json);
        }
    });
});
function createJSTree(jsondata) {
    $('#simpleJsTree').jstree({
        "core": {
            "check_callback": true,
            'data': jsondata

        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu"],
        "contextmenu": {
            "items": function ($node) {
                var tree = $("#simpleJsTree").jstree(true);
                return {
                    "Create": {
                        "separator_before": false,
                        "separator_after": true,
                        "label": "Create",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            tree.create_node($node);
                        }

                    },
                    "Rename": {
                        "separator_before": false,
                        "separator_after": false,
                        "label": "Rename",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            tree.edit($node);
                        }
                    },
                    "Remove": {
                        "separator_before": false,
                        "separator_after": false,
                        "label": "Remove",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            tree.delete_node($node);
                        }
                    },
                    "Upload": {
                        "seperator_beore": false,
                        "seperator_after": false,
                        "label": "Upload"
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }).bind('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Create",
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
    
}
```

here binding of create function to context menu is not working
this is the partial view where i m calling modal popup to take parent node

```
@model ParentClass
<div class="modal fade" id="Addnode">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"id="Addnode">Add Node</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs- 
                dismiss="modal">
                    <span>X</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" 
          method="post">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ParentName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ParentName"class="form- 
                    control" />
                        <span asp-validation- 
            for="ParentName"class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
               data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
           data-save="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and site.js file to show modal popup

```
$(function () {
    var placeElement = $('#placeHolder');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            placeElement.html(data);
            placeElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        });
    });
    placeElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function 
           (event) {
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var sendData = form.serialize();
        $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            placeElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making ajax call with the codes:

```
var sendData = form.serialize();
$.post(actionUrl, sendData)
```

controller in MVC project read data from request form by default,So you need to add
[FromBody]

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody]ParentClass parent)
        {
            
                _db.parent.Add(parent);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("_HomePartial", parent);
        }
```

if you have further issue on the case,please show more details of the error

Comment: yes now i am getting the new parent node ,now i have to make it for child also ,means i have given context menu to the js tree ,for the options like create, delete, and rename i dont now how to bind all of them if u know then help me out

Comment: now i want create child node using context menu and have to pass controller call to context menu action ,i m not getting what to do help me out

Comment: this document may help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#complex-types-1

Comment: my question is to add child node to selected parent node using context menu ,in my context menu i have create option now i want attach that functionality to create option

Comment: Have you missed  to post the codes related with contextmenu?I didn't see any codes related

Comment: i did not mention the code regarding the contxt menu ,that i hv the code for context menu where i have to call post create function of controller

Answer (score 0):

I use [jsuites](https://jsuites.net/docs/modal) components to create my projects. I faced the same problem and found this library.

```html
<html>
    <script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

    <jsuites-modal title="Webcomponent Modal" closed="true" width="600" height="480">
        This is an example how to create a modal based on the custom HTML javascript modal.
    </jsuites-modal>

    <input type='button' value='Open the modal' onclick="document.querySelector('jsuites-modal').modal.open()" class='plain' />

    <script>
        document.querySelector('jsuites-modal').addEventListener('onopen', function() {
            console.log('Modal is open');
        });
        document.querySelector('jsuites-modal').addEventListener('onclose', function() {
            console.log('Modal is closed');
        });
    </script>
</html>
```